# How to remove line breaks or merge lines in a txt file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file that contains "blocks of consecutive lines", each block representing one observation whereas the different lines within each block represent the value of one variable of the corresponding observation. 
I worked my way to here using python and I would like to read the .txt file into Stata. Therefore, I would like to remove the line breaks within each block to get one single line containing all the information for one block/observation (delimited by commas). The linebreaks between blocks/observations, however, should persist.

The order of the information on variables are in the same order for all blocks/observations, but number of variables per observation varies (at the lower end).
my .txt (encoding = 'ascii') file looks like this:

obs1_var1,

obs1_var2,

obs1_var3,

obs2_var1,

obs2_var2,

obs2_var3,

obs2_var4,

obs3_var1,

obs3_var2,

obs3_var3,

Comment: It is not clear what the input is, nor what the desired output is.

Comment: `with open(file) as f:..lines = f.read().strip().split()` ?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of examplary input file and also the code that you tried to achieve it.

Comment: I have added a screenshot below on how the list looks like at the moment. I also tried to describe where I'd like to go from there. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
with open('my_file.txt','r') as f:
    # lines should hold the data with no new lines
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the balderman's answer:

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
```

This part will create the list of lines of whole file. To create a single line for variables in each block you can just use dictionary to store variables in each block.
Example:

```
block_vars = {}
for line in lines:
    block_name = line[:4]
    if block_name not in block_vars.keys():
        block_vars[block_name] = []        #declaring as list store the lines in that block
    block_vars[block_name].append(line)    #append the line to list with same block name
```

block_vars dictionary contains list of lines associated with particular block. You can use *'delimiter'.join(list_name)* to get single line output.

Comment: `with open('WS16_17/Bachelor-Studiengänge - Hauptfach_sorted.txt','r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    # lines should hold the data with no new lines
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
f.close()`

Comment: This code (thanks to @balderman) creates a list called lines that looks as follows:
[https://i.imgur.com/Au41MY3.png]
Consecutive lines belong to the same observation (lecture title, credits, type, semester, lecturer etc.). What I need from here is to somehow get this into a dataset, preferably in Stata. Note that the order of "variables" (title, credits, type etc.) is always the same, but not every block/observation (separated through empty list elements) has the same length. This is why I am not sure whether the dictionary works, as it requires to determine how many lines make one block?

Comment: Christian, I got your point. I can see your file doesn't follow structure. I have also seen that each block starts with keyword "VName". If this pattern is followed throughout the file then you can just separate each block w.r.t that.